# Почему в моей верстке одна секция накладывается на другую , и при добавлении фона одной секции он добавляется и другой секции

Tags: вёрстка

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 
}
/*Header*/
/*---------------------*/
.wrap {
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 background-color: #ba0000;
}

.wrap p{
 font-size: 16px;
 color:  #fff;
}

.list {
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.logo {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.main-nav {
 height: 120px;
 line-height: 120px;
 background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.main-nav ul{
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.main-nav ul li {
 padding-right: 40px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
 color: #ba0000;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.main-nav ul li a:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #ba0000;
 transform:  scaleX(0);
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover:after{
 content: '';
 transform: scaleX(1)
}

.search {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}

.search i {
 position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
 right: 30px;
 color: #fff;
}
/*Main*/
/*-----------------------*/

.wrap_3 {
 height: 82vh;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg,#ba0000,transparent),  url(../image/main_bg.png) no-repeat;
}

.wrap_3 h1 {
 padding-top: 130px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
}
.wrap_3 span {
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 position: absolute;
 top: 520px;
 left: 400px;
}
.main_text {
 color: #ffcc00;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-top: 85px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.advantage {
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.advantage a{
 width: 4px;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.block a{
 font-size: 16px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 padding: 20px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 transition:  all 0.3s ease;
}

.block a:hover {
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 color: #ba0000;
 border:none;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 18px rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.4);
}
/*Section*/
/*----------------------*/
section {
 height: 740px;
}

 section h2 {
  padding-top: 125px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  color: #ba0000;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 900;
 }

 section .list {
  height: 135px;
 }

 .list h4 {
  color: #ba0000;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 800;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .list p {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
 }

 .list a{
  color: #222;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: -40px;
 }

 .list i{
 color: #ba0000;
 }

 .strong {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 31px;
  height: 360px;
  background-color: #ba0000;
 }

 .strong h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }

 .strong span {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  margin-top: 31px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
 }

 .strong p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
 }

 .location {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
 }

.location p{
 height: 50px;
 width: 180px;
 background-color: #9d0000;
 padding: 15px 40px 15px 21px;
}

.location i {
 width: 65px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #ffcc00;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ba0000;
 font-size: 16px;
}

 .button_yellow {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  color: #ba0000;
  padding: 18px 30px;
  background-color:  #ffcc00;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 18px rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.4);
  margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .button_yellow:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ba0000;
 }
 /*Section-2*/
/*------------------------------*/

.wrap_5 {
 height: 750px;
 background:url(../image/sec_2_bg.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-blend-mode: multiply;
 background-color: rgba(39,15,4,0.6);
}

.sec_2_h2 {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding-top: 170px;
 padding-left: 70px;
 margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.block_play {
 padding: 21px 21px 21px 15px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color:  #ffcc00;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 48%;
 margin-bottom: 210px;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 18px rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.4);
}

.block_play span{
 width: 16px;
 height: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 color: #ba0000;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: 900;
}

.sec_2_image {
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 375px;
}

.sec_2_image img {
 width: 375px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: -3px;
}

.sec_2_text {
 width: 375px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 18px rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.4);
}

.sec_2_image h4{
 color: #ba0000;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.sec_2_image i {
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #ffcc00;
}

.sec_2_image p {
 line-height: 3px;
 color: #777;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.sec_2_image p:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/*Section-3*/
/*----------------------*/

/*Вот ошибка*/
.wrap_6 {
 padding-top: 400px;
 background-color: #ba0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Work</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>
 <script src="script/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="lang col-md-2">
      <p>English  &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></p>
     </div>
     <div class="listcol-md-4 offset-md-6">
      <p><i class="fas fa-users"></i>  &nbsp;Contact Center &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      Country Profile &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-nav">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 logo">
      <img src="image/logo.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8 nav">
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Express</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parcel & Ecommerce </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logistics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1 search offset-1">
      <img src="image/circle.png" alt="">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="wrap_3">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <h1 class="col-md-6">We Deliver <br>With Speed</h1>
     <span class="col-md-3"></span>
     <p class="main_text col-md-8">When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambledit <br> to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
     <p class="advantage col-md-7">Amazing &nbsp;&nbsp;   <a href="#"></a>  &nbsp;&nbsp; Quick  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#"></a>  24/7 Supports</p>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="block">
     <a href="#" class="col-md-2">Learn More</a>
     <a href="#" class="col-md-3">dhl worldwide</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <section class="section_1">
  <div class="wrap_4">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <h2 class="col-md-12">Awesome Services</h2>
     <div class="col-md-3 list">
      <img src="image/item_1.png" alt="">
      <h4>Express Services</h4>
      <p>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 list">
      <img src="image/item_2.png" alt="">
      <h4>Express Services</h4>
      <p>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 list ">
      <img src="image/item_3.png" alt="">
      <h4>Express Services</h4>
      <p>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 strong">
      <h4>DHl Worldwide</h4>
      <span></span>
      <p>When an unknown prot printer type and scra</p>
      <div class="location">
       <p class>Location &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
      <a href="" class="button_yellow">Explore list</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="section_2">
  <div class="wrap_5">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <h2 class="col-md-10 sec_2_h2 offset-2">One of the best international service provider</h2>
    <div class="block_play">
     <span class="col-md-2 play"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="sec_2_image">
     <div class="sec_2_block col-md-4">
      <img src="image/sec_2_1.png " alt="">
      <div class="sec_2_text">
       <h4>Aerospace Provider</h4>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> When an unknown printer took.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Make a type specimen book.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> It has survived.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Airlines unknown specimen.</p>
      </div>     
     </div>
     <div class="sec_2_block col-md-4">
      <img src="image/sec_2_1.png"  alt="">
      <div class="sec_2_text">
       <h4>Poppins Proved</h4>
       <p><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> When an unknown printer took.</p>
       <p><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Make a type specimen book.</p>
       <p><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> It has survived.</p>
       <p><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Airlines unknown specimen.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="sec_2_block col-md-4">
      <img src="image/sec_2_1.png"  alt="">
      <div class="sec_2_text">
       <h4>Airline Specimen</h4>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> When an unknown printer took.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Make a type specimen book.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> It has survived.</p>
       <p> <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Airlines unknown specimen.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="section_3">
  <div class="wrap_6">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <h3 class="col-md-12">Excellence. Simply delivered.</h3>
    <p class="col-md-8">International express deliveries; global freight forwarding by air, sea, road and rail;
    warehousing solutions from packaging, to repairs, to storage; mail deliveries worldwide;
    and other customized logistic services – with everything DHL does, we
    help connect people and improve their lives.</p>
    <a href="#" class="col-md-2 offset-2">learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так пойдёт?

```
.wrap_6 {
margin-top: 160px;
padding-top: 240px;
background-color: #ba0000;
}
```